# I am getting error in Power BI while changing Date Type

Tags: date, error-handling, powerbi

Everyone, I am currently doing a project in Power BI but I am getting errors.

While transforming data initially, in Power Query, when I change the data type from (Text) to type (date), it only shows 2021 at the end of every date, like this 1/18/2021.

Even before it was date of 2019 like jan-19 but after only shows this. 1/18/2021 for every date. So please someone can help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look  how to produce a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It's assuming the 18/19 refer to the day of the month rather than the year. Try replacing "-" with "-20" before converting to date using the Transform > Replace Values tool.

[image: Replace Values screenshot]

```
Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"-","-20",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Date"})
```

Comment: I did it and somehow it worked Thanks. But I couldn't understood the logic behind it. Can you explain it please. It would be great thanks again.

Comment: With two digits, it assumes 18/19 refers to the day of the month. When you have the full year, 2018/2019, there is no ambiguity to get wrong.

Comment: ok but why replace with just "-20" why not "-19" or any other number?

Comment: I was assuming these years were from this century. If your dates span before and after 2000, then you'll need a bit more work since you probably don't want years 2099 instead of 1999.

Comment: ok i think i got it. so when I replaced "-" with "-20", it putted 20 before every year right? like 20-19 , as before it was just 19 and now its 2019 so power can understand it better, is that right?

Comment: Yep. `Jan-18` becomes `Jan-2018` which gets interpreted as January 2018 rather than January 18th 2021.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping